# python:assignment of list item as true and false

Tags: python

I have a Python list and I want to assign all possible combinations of `True` and `False` values to all the elements of the list.

Suppose I have list `list1 = ['a', 'b']`, so I want a new list as `[['t','t'],['t','f'],['f','t'],['f','f']]`, which are all the possible combinations of `True` and `False` value of the given list item.

If I have `n` element in the given list then I should `2^n` element in my new list and each of the inner lists should contain `n` element either as 't' or 'f'.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: This question has been asked maybe 5 billion times before.

Answer (score 2):

Use `itertools.product`.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.product(["t", "f"], repeat=2))
[('t', 't'), ('t', 'f'), ('f', 't'), ('f', 'f')]
>>> list(itertools.product(["t", "f"], repeat=3))
[('t', 't', 't'), ('t', 't', 'f'), ('t', 'f', 't'), ('t', 'f', 'f'), ('f', 't', 't'), ('f', 't', 'f'), ('f', 'f', 't'), ('f', 'f', 'f')]
>>> #etc
```

Comment: thanks a lot kevin. but the new list i want it in a nested list format.what should I do for that?

Comment: If you mean "How do I get a list of lists instead of a list of tuples?", then you could do `list_of_lists = map(list, list_of_tuples)`.

Answer (score 0):

look at `itertools.product`:

```
import itertools

true_or_false = list(itertools.produkt(*[['t','f']]*n))
```

Comment: Thans Daniel for your help